# Do constexpr functions have to be defined before they are used?

Tags: c++, constexpr, constexpr-function

see code below, f() is defined below main function is regarded as ill-formed ?
could anyone give me an explanation for this ?

```
constexpr  int f ();
void indirection ();
int main () {
  constexpr int n = f (); // ill-formed, `int f ()` is not yet defined
  indirection ();
}
constexpr int f () {
  return 0;
}
void indirection () {
  constexpr int n = f (); // ok
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++14 standard provides the following code snippet (shortened by me for convenience):

```
constexpr void square(int &x); // OK: declaration

struct pixel { 
    int x;
    int y;
    constexpr pixel(int); 
};

constexpr pixel::pixel(int a)
    : x(a), y(x) 
{ square(x); }

constexpr pixel small(2); // error: square not defined, so small(2)
                        // is not constant so constexpr not satisfied

constexpr void square(int &x) { // OK: definition
   x *= x;
}
```

The solution is to move the definition of `square` above the the declaration of `small`.

From the above we can get to the conclusion that it's fine to forward declare `constexpr` functions, but their definitions have to be available *prior* to their first use.

Answer (score 2):

A `constexpr` something has to be known at compile time, at each point where it's used.

This is essentially the same as you cannot declare a variable of an incomplete type, even if that type is fully defined later in the same source.